# Lines of Code has been decreased in Sonar 5.1.2

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

In our project we have upgraded Sonar and observed that Lines of Code has been decreased significantly. It has resulted in increase in code complexity.
Old SonarQube version: 3.7.1
New SonarQube Version: 5.1.2

I further drilled down, and found that for a same file old and new version of Sonar are reporting different lines of code.

File Name: cnsxxxx.c

Old Sonar (3.7.1)
Lines:  8,591 ::
Lines of code:  8,508

New Sonar (5.1.2)
Lines: 8,591 ::
Lines of code 6,657

Its important to note that total number of lines are same, but LOC has been decreased significantly.
Any inputs to cater this issue.

Attached Image of code file LOC from Old and New Sonar.
[LOC Compare of Old and New Sonar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXXP6.png)

Comment: Which C plugin is being used ?

Comment: When you answer @SimonBrandhof-SonarSource's question, you should also include the version numbers, old and new.

Comment: Thanks @SimonBrandhof-SonarSource for response. On Old Sonar (3.7.1) I can see two C plugins. a) C/C++ (SonarSource) [cpp] version 1.5.2 b) C version 1.8. On latest Sonar (5.1.2), there is no C plugin installed. One plugin "C / C++ / Objective-C" is available for installation.

Comment: If no C plugin is installed in 5.1 then no metrics can be computed on C files, so I don't understand how you get figures. Note that you should reach the SonarSource support team if you're experimenting the SonarSource C/C++ plugin.

Comment: You should upgrade to SonarQube 5.6 LTS